# Method on how to ask and allow storage permissions on Android through using MAUI

Tags: c#, android, maui, android-permissions, syncfusion

The Android Application I am creating will need to access certain files on the public storage location of the Android phone. I know I will need to modify the AndroidManifes.XML as well as ask permissions. I have read through the MAUI documentations and have seen the permissions page. However, I am uncertain on how to implement the examples on that page. Where exactly in my MAUI Android application would I need to use their code provided. I would like the permissions to be asked when the Application is launched. Can anyone please explain in more detail on exactly where to use the permissions codes.

Here is my MainPage.xaml.cs code. I know this is used for location permission, but I am using this just as a test.

`

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration;
using Syncfusion.XlsIO;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Maui.Storage;

namespace MauiApp3
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        int count = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
           
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckAndRequestLocationPermission()
        {
            PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                return status;

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied && DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
            {
                // Prompt the user to turn on in settings
                // On iOS once a permission has been denied it may not be requested again from the application
                return status;
            }

            if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>())
            {
                // Prompt the user with additional information as to why the permission is needed
            }

            status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();

            return status;
        }

        private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = Task.Run(async () => await CheckAndRequestLocationPermission());
            result.Wait();
            ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine();

            //Initialize IApplication
            Syncfusion.XlsIO.IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;

            //Load the file into stream

            string rootPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim).AbsolutePath;
            string backingFile = Path.Combine(rootPath, "Proof.xlsx");
            //Stream reader = new StreamReader(backingFile);

            var reader = new MemoryStream();

            FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(backingFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            //Assembly executingAssembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            //Stream inputStream = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(backingFile);

            //Loads or open an existing workbook through Open method of IWorkbooks
            IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(inputStream, ExcelOpenType.Automatic);

            IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

            //worksheet.Range["A3"].Text = "Mooi";
            //worksheet.Range["A4"].Text = "10";
            worksheet.Range["A5"].Text = "Brilliant";

            string savePath = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments).ToString();
            string saveFile = Path.Combine(savePath, "Proof.xlsx");

            FileStream stream = new FileStream(saveFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            workbook.SaveAs(stream);
            workbook.Close();
            excelEngine.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, you can read the official document about the [Maui App Lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle).

> I would like the permissions to be asked when the Application is
> launched

You can put the code about asking permission in lifecycle method of the App.cs. Such as:

```
   public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();

            // ask permission here
        }

        protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
        {
            Window window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);

            window.Created += (s, e) =>
            {
                // ask persmission here
            };

            return window;
        }
        
        protected override void OnStart()
        {
           // ask persmission here
        }
    }
```

> Where exactly in my MAUI Android application would I need to use their code provided

For the android, you can put the code in the `\Platforms\Android\MainActivity.cs`.

```
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // ask permission here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below code snippet to make the app request storage access when the app is launched at the first time.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        RequestStoragePermission();
    }

    async void RequestStoragePermission()
    {
        var status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();

        if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            // Permission has been granted. You can perform your file operations here.
        }
        else
        {
            // Permission is denied. You can handle this case accordingly.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Mohan I will ty it out and mark the answer as correct if successful. I have another related question however. I am working with Android 11 (API 30) and and most people indicate that you cannot write to the plain documents folder on your phone meaning "/storage/emulated/0/documents". The reason why I ask is I would like to save the excel file to this folder, allow my app to make changes to file and then later open it with the excel app on my phone to view it. But apparently this cannot be done. Access to the documents folder will always be denied with version Android 11 (API 30).

Comment: By the way, I managed to manipulate the file if stored in the "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com...etc" path, but you are not allowed access to this path when working on the phone, only when connected to a computer. Hope understand my dilemma.